# What kind of travel documents should be used for a Chinese citizen to take flights from Hong Kong and ferry to Shekou?

Tags: china, hong-kong

There is a ferry from Hong Kong Airport to Shekou, usable for connecting passengers without passing immigration.

If I am from Shenzhen and want to take a flight from Hong Kong to Beijing by means of the Shekou - Hong Kong Airport ferry, what kind of travel document should I use? On the return trip from Beijing, what kind of travel document should I present in order to board the flight to Hong Kong?

Answer (score 1):

Shekou-HKG-PEK is easy. You just need your passport. The ferry will take you to the secure area of HKG. You're not entering HK, and you can only board this ferry if you have a valid plane ticket.

PEK-HKG-Shekou is another story. You would have to convince the airline that you will not try and enter HK.

Then again, one might wonder why you'd go to so much trouble when you have direct flights SZX-PEK...

Comment: flights to HKG are much cheaper than to SZX

Comment: Not necessarily. I just checked on CSA's web site, they have return flights SZX-PEK as low as 1,350 rmb.